# How to get the final checked value in Radio Group in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, radio-button, android-radiogroup

[image]

I've a `custom listview` like shown in the picture. Below is the code of that `custom listview`

```
    public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> hMap;

    String question, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, value;

    String[] answer;
    QuestionAnswer qa = new QuestionAnswer();

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        data = d;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_questions, parent,
                false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        final RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radio3);

        hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hMap = data.get(position);

        tv.setText(hMap.get("questions"));

        question = hMap.get("questions");

        /*Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = hMap.keySet().iterator();
        while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            value = (String) hMap.get("questions");
            System.out.println("mother fucker " + value);
            qa.setQuestion(value);

            questions(value);

        }*/

        rb1.setText(hMap.get("op1"));
        opt1 = hMap.get("op1");

        rb2.setText(hMap.get("op2"));
        opt2 = hMap.get("op2");

        rb3.setText(hMap.get("op3"));
        opt3 = hMap.get("op3");

        rb4.setText(hMap.get("op4"));
        opt4 = hMap.get("op4");

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int childCount = group.getChildCount();
        for (int x = 0; x < childCount; x++) {
            RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(x);

            if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {

                String ans = btn.getText().toString();


            }
        }

    }



}
```

The user may click on any of the options. But I need to get the `final value` that is `selected`. If the user selects Anil and then John and moves to second question where he selects Sick and then selects Play. I need to get these final answers, i.e John and Play. How do I do this ? Please help.
And this is how I fill the `custom listview`.

```
    public class Account extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> radioData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv;
    RadioGroup rg;
    Data data;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account, container, false);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final Button bStart = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button bSubmit = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        rg = (RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        });

        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        String questions[] = { "what is your name", "why are you here" };
        String op1[] = { "Anil", "Play" };
        String op2[] = { "John", "Sick" };
        String op3[] = { "David", "Write" };
        String op4[] = { "Akshaya", "Act" };

        for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hMap1.put("questions", questions[i]);
            hMap1.put("op1", op1[i]);
            hMap1.put("op2", op2[i]);
            hMap1.put("op3", op3[i]);
            hMap1.put("op4", op4[i]);

            radioData.add(hMap1);
        }


        /*ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), radioData,
                R.layout.custom_questions, new String[] { "questions", "op1",
                        "op2", "op3", "op4" }, new int[] { R.id.textView1,
                        R.id.radio0, R.id.radio1, R.id.radio2, R.id.radio3 });*/

        CustomArrayAdapter adap = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), radioData);

        lv.setAdapter(adap);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to know the state of all radiogroups? Where in your code? Does the onCheckedChanged() work? Can you 'grab' the choosen option there?

Comment: yes, onCheckedChanged() works and I want to get the values on bSubmit button click.

Comment: Add a <Boolean> ArrayList to your adapter. Instantiate false for ngroups*4 items. Then in  onCheckedChanged set to true for the right item in the group. (Set the other group members to false). In nSubmit click inspect the array.

Comment: Alternatively you could add an <Int> ArrayList (initiate to -1) for the choosen option number.

Comment: @theanilpaudel,have you try my code ?

Comment: @theanilpaudel What do you mean by final? Do you want the last selected radiobutton's value? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in your submit button's onClick as follows:

```
bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Id of checked radio button
        int checkedId = rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        //Text of that id
        if(checkedId > 0) {  //condition to check that at radio button is selected.
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            String text = radioButton.getText().toString();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `rgroup` ? And at he moment there are two groups.

Comment: the checkedId gives null value.

Comment: @greenapps I have just gave OP example. He must understand that he would need to do the same for both radio groups. :)

Comment: @theanilpaudel Is radio group id proper? and is any radio button checked in it?

Comment: @MysticMagic yes, radio group id is correct and a button is checked

Comment: checkedId is null or that line is giving null pointer exception? @theanilpaudel

Comment: @theanilpaudel rgroup is null. Have you initialized it in this activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63406/discussion-between-mysticmagic-and-theanilpaudel).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Take one **HashMap** which hold **Interger** as key and **String** as value and try put all four **RadioButton** id as key and **RadioButton** text as value and try set Tag this **HashMap** to **RadioGroup**.now when any **RadioButton** Check Change Listener called get **HashMap** from **RadioGroup** Tag and get checked **RadioButton** text from **HashMap** using checked **RadioButton** id.

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_questions, parent,false);
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            holder.radio0 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            holder.radio1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            holder.radio2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            holder.radio3 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio3);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView1.setText(data.get(position).get("questions"));
        holder.radio0.setText(data.get(position).get("op1"));
        holder.radio1.setText(data.get(position).get("op2"));
        holder.radio2.setText(data.get(position).get("op3"));
        holder.radio3.setText(data.get(position).get("op4"));

        HashMap<Integer,String> radioMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        radioMap.put(holder.radio0.getId(),holder.radio0.getText().toString());
        radioMap.put(holder.radio1.getId(),holder.radio1.getText().toString());
        radioMap.put(holder.radio2.getId(),holder.radio2.getText().toString());
        radioMap.put(holder.radio3.getId(),holder.radio3.getText().toString());

        holder.radioGroup1.setTag(radioMap);
        holder.radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                HashMap<Integer,String> data = (HashMap<Integer,String>) group.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context,data.get(checkedId),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView textView1;
        RadioGroup radioGroup1;
        RadioButton radio0;
        RadioButton radio1;
        RadioButton radio2;
        RadioButton radio3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i see nothing that would help the OP to solve his problem. Why do you think it does?

Comment: You should also write what was the issue and what are you trying to suggest?

Comment: @PareshMayani,i try to put explanation about my ans but theanilpaudel never response me.

Comment: I can't see any explanation in your answer! My suggestion to you is to put some details about issue and solution you post! It would help someone in future to understand it exactly. I have found most of your answers with **complete code** and **without issue details**.

Comment: @PareshMayani,Okay sir but i realize that you try to correct all my ans for this thank you very much and i take care of your suggestion.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Cheers man! Hope you will follow this practice while posting answers.

Comment: @PareshMayani,Sir can you please let me know one thing how you realize  to check all my ans ?